# Can you use an associated object gathered by someone else to teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

A bard has recently joined our party. In addition to adding a certain *savoir faire*, they can teleport, so we now have two teleporters.  The possibilities are endless.

I have a small collection of objects I've retrieved from various locations to use to teleport back to those places.  I am seeing no reason I can't give one to the bard, so that they can use it to teleport us to some place we visited before the bard joined us.

The *[teleport](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport)* spell says (emphasis added):

> **Familiarity.** "Permanent circle" means a permanent teleportation circle whose sigil sequence you know. "Associated object" means that **you possess an object taken from the desired destination** within the last six months, such as a book from a wizard's library, bed linen from a royal suite, or a chunk of marble from a lich's secret tomb.

RAW it looks to me like the caster doesn't have to be the one to have "taken" the object, am I missing anything?

I'm going to ask the GM, but I want to go in with the facts straight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You are correct

Nothing in the spell states that the spell caster needs to need to have been the person that removed the object from the location, merely that you posses it.

In my campaign, my bard is talking to people that have visited foreign lands and asking for trinkets and souvenirs. "Oh, you went to the Elven Temple? Did you happen to bring an extra copy of their hymnal?"

The only thing to remember is that the object must have been removed within six months. So you could go to a museum and start touching objects, but unless they were only recently excavated, you might end up in a warehouse.

Comment: I wonder if visiting resets the clock on the trinket. Could have some interesting results in the game world, like wizards taking the same vacation trip every 6 months as a global phenomenon. *"They're just weird that way, my boy, magic does that to your head."*

Comment: My wizard's GM caved and agreed re-visiting resets the clock after my wizard started picking up a different acorn or stick and I would describe *how* it was different. The whole thing doesn't bear too much examination. How trivial an item? How long does it have been at the target destination to be considered associated? Is your shoe associated with every place you've been? Probably not. Your house? The cobbler's house?

Comment: @Jack We're dealing with the magical concept of *contagion* here: things that were once part of a whole retain a link when separated. I'd rule that the item needs to have *mystical significance* to the place it's from -- an actual piece of the location is the easy way to do this.  But no, bringing an item back momentarily doesn't reset the timer, in my mind. You'd need to drop off the thing you took before and pick a new item of significance to reset the timer.  That might be as easy as plucking a new acorn off an oak or as complicated as stealing a new knickknack from a shelf.

Comment: To follow your example of shoes, I would say that relatively short-lived consumer goods don't count at all, unless they belong to a larger collection or have been in the place for a long time. A hat or shoe doesn't *belong* to a house. It's not really *from* anywhere. But a shoe from Imelda Marcos's famous collection *would* be 'from' that place. It's *part of a collection* in a mysical/spiritual/conceptual sense, and so retains a link to the rest of the collection. Or, say, a pen taken from your mentor's desk is part of the office, even if the pen itself isn't that long-lived.

Comment: Notably "The destination you choose must be known to you" so touching objects in a museum cannot land you in a warehouse if the warehouse is not known to you

Comment: @findusl, You skipped the next sentence that says, _"Your familiarity with the destination determines whether you arrive there successfully. The DM rolls d100 and consults the table."_ The table includes everything from Magic Circle and familiar to "Description". So while just touching the object would not work, hearing about the location they stored the items previously might be enough.

Comment: @MivaScott You wrote "So you could go to a museum and start touching objects, but unless they were only recently excavated, you might end up in a warehouse." That doesn't sound like the Warehouse is the intended target for your teleport spell. So you are saying if you have heard of the warehouse, you could land there even if it is not your intended target? The spell clearly says "Teleports you [...] to a destination you select". Although that can fail so I guess while I don't agree with your reasoning, it could be a question of its own.